# 100% height overflows my flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox, quill

I created a somewhat holy grail layout with flex box. This works completely like it should without any scrollbars - until I insert the Quill text editor into my content_wrapper container. In this container there is the top toolbar and also a main div for the editor inside.

When I try to set the editor's height to 100% it will create an overflow (I think because it takes the 100% of the body but does not recognize that there is also my custom **blue** toolbar above it).

How do I need to setup my page, that the editor does not go outside of the page at the bottom?

**Run this code snippet on a full view page please!**

```css
html,body { 
 height:100%; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main_wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.content_wrapper {
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

aside.sidebar {
 background-color: grey;
 flex: 0 0 195px;
}

header.topbar {
 background-color: blue;
 flex: 0 0 50px;
}

main {
 background-color: white;
 flex: 1;
}

.contentbar {
 background-color: grey;
 flex: 0 0 405px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Prototype</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Text Editor Theme included stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
</head>

<body>
 <div class="main_wrapper">
  <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
  <div class="content_wrapper">
   <header class="topbar"></header>
   <main>
    <div id="editor"></div>
   </main>
  </div>
  <div class="contentbar"></div>
 </div>
</body>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
 
  var options = {
      bounds: 'main',
   theme: 'snow'
 };
 var editor = new Quill('#editor', options);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS's `calc()` function.

The tool-bar above the editor is taking some space, you should decrease that much space from the bottom of `.ql-container`. The `height` of the `.ql-toolbar` may vary on different screens.

Like:

```
.ql-container {
  height: calc(100% - 42px); /* 100% - height of 'ql-toolbar' */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
html,body { 
 height:100%; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main_wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.content_wrapper {
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

aside.sidebar {
 background-color: grey;
 flex: 0 0 195px;
}

header.topbar {
 background-color: blue;
 flex: 0 0 50px;
}

main {
 background-color: white;
 flex: 1;
}

.contentbar {
 background-color: grey;
 flex: 0 0 405px;
}

.ql-container {
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Prototype</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Text Editor Theme included stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
</head>

<body>
 <div class="main_wrapper">
  <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
  <div class="content_wrapper">
   <header class="topbar"></header>
   <main>
    <div id="editor"></div>
   </main>
  </div>
  <div class="contentbar"></div>
 </div>
</body>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.5/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
 
  var options = {
      bounds: 'main',
   theme: 'snow'
 };
 var editor = new Quill('#editor', options);
</script>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm for me your snippet still has the same overflow when I view it on Full Page mode :(

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I saw this code actually works, it just got overwritten by the editor code. I wil ltry this in my local prototype and try that it does not get overwritten when the editor creates its code - give me a sec :)

Comment: Indeed it works (I just needed to adjust the css loading queue)! Thank you for this solution! I really wonder why Quill does not calculate this by itself anyways...

Comment: @olop01 Its my pleasure!